# Vector of Vectors of Vectors of int

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How to create a matrix like this:

```
std::vector <std::vector <int*>> matrix;
```

However I only found examples for those:

```
std::vector <std::vector <int>> matrix;
```

OR

```
std::vector <std::vector <int> *> matrix;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. For any `vector<T>`, you create a object of type T, and pass it to `push_back`. If T is an `int*`, you give it an `int*`; if it's a `vector<int*>`, you give it a `vector<int*>`.

Comment: Just add space between double `>`: `std::vector <std::vector <int*> > matrix;`. Or what is the question?

Comment: you have already implemented it. what is the question?

Comment: The reason you can't find anything on `std::vector <std::vector <int*>> matrix;` is because it is almost always a really, really bad idea. There is little to be gained from storing a pointer to a single `int` and a great deal to lose, and if you wish to store an array of `int`s, `std::vector <std::vector <std::vector <int>>>` matrix is most likely the better option. There is too little information here to recommend a better path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<std::vector<int *>> matrix;` is exactly what you need. That says:

```
// This is a vector
//               ...which itself contains vectors 
//                                             ...of int pointers
std::vector<        std::vector<                  int *>         > matrix;
```

Here's how you might initialize it:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int *>> matrix;
matrix.resize(10); // matrix now contains 10 vectors of int pointers
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    matrix[i].resize(20);
}
// matrix is now a 10x20 two-dimensional array

// add another row, to get to 11x20
std::vector<int *> last_row(20);
matrix.push_back(last_row);
```

Does that help?

Edit: In response to the question in the comments, here's how you would initialize it with a bunch of `new`ed `int`s. This is not really recommended—the pointer chasing, plus the syntactic overhead will *not* be a win over just using a vector-of-vectors-of-int... but it's certainly *legal*.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int *>> matrix;
matrix.push_back(std::vector<int *>());
matrix[0].push_back(new int(10)); // matrix is now 1x1
std::cout << *(matrix[0][0]) << std::endl; // prints 10
```

Comment: Helps a lot! Thank you. There is any possibility to do it without knowing in advance it size? (e.g 10x20). Maybe using **new int** in a certain form?

Comment: Edited in response. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot!:):):). I wish I could give you 10 plus!!!